# HTML/CSS - Check for Missing File References

Tags: html, css, reference

Are there any plugins or tools that can examine HTML and related CSS files for missing references such as images? I have a very complex page that something is displaying incorrectly on, but I'm having trouble tracking down what exactly is missing or where it is referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about firebug?  Its "net" tab will show you the stream of requests your browser is making, and any missing files will appear as a 404.

Comment: Net tab is perfect. I figured the solution would be part of Firebug, but I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5):

Try the Firebug add-on for Firefox. You can look at the net monitor to see all the fetches that are happening while your page loads. You can easily weed out 404 (not found) responses.

Comment: Thanks Ates! I gave the answer to David just because he beat you to it. No hard feelings ;)